# Wordpress Menu wont stay top

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu, themes

Im working on a wordpress site and i have my template that im trying to work with and i want to make the menu stay fixed to the top of the screen when scrolling down the page. i know enough bootstrap that if i could get it integrated correctly i can use it to make it stay or just code a new menu entirely but im unsure where i need to go in wordpress to achieve this or if there is a plugin that does? this. Thank you ahead of time for any help.

I tried adding the following class to the menu but it didn't help, the code is Bootstrap.

I did remember to close the div but it didn't help.

Comment: <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

Comment: Thats the code i used.

Comment: Its kinda hard to assist with code when there isn't any code on display which is not just one line :p

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in your class name, I dont think CSS allows it.
If the class name is "navbar-fixed-top", this should make it fixed on the top!

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1030;
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I added the CSS in my stylesheet and im trying to apply the class but it's not responding. Im putting it in the header.php file

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css"/> on your php's header.

Comment: You can have a space in the class attribute to reference multiple classes. So `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">` would be in both the `navbar` class and the `navbar-fixed-top` class.